# How to assign role(s) from a register form to a new user in the RegisterController at Laravel 7?

Tags: php, laravel, roles, user-management

**Description**

I'm new to PHP/Laravel and i set up a little user/role management. I only need a register and login function. The "register" function is only accessible for the admin.
I used the standard auth setup as it is described here at the Laravel [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authentication).

At the moment every new user gets the role "student" as you can see in this snippet:

```
 protected function create(array $data)
  {

    $user = User::create([
      'name' => $data['name'],
      'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
    ]);

    // every new user gets the role "student"

    $role = Role::select("id")->where("role", "student")->first();

    $user->roles()->attach($role);

    return $user;
  }
```

Thats the corresponding blade for the create user form:

```
<h2>Benutzer Erstellen</h2>
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('register') }}" class="form-container">
  @csrf

  <h3>Neuen Benutzer anlegen</h3>
  {{-- <h4>Benutzerrechte:</h4>
  <div class="row-container">
  <div class="row-grid">

    <label for="name">{{ __('Login Name:') }}</label>

    <input id="name" type="text" class="edit-input @error('name') is-invalid @enderror" name="name"
      value="{{ old('name') }}" required autocomplete="name" autofocus placeholder="Name">

    @error('name')
    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
      <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
    </span>
    @enderror

  </div>

  <div class="row-grid">

    <label for="password">{{ __('Passwort:') }}</label>

    <input id="password" type="password" class="edit-input @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" name="password"
      required autocomplete="new-password" placeholder="Passwort">

    @error('password')
    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
      <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
    </span>
    @enderror


  </div>
  <div class="row-grid">
    <label for="password-confirm">{{ __('Passwort wiederholen:') }}</label>
    <input id="password-confirm" type="password" class="edit-input" name="password_confirmation" required
      autocomplete="new-password" placeholder="Passwort wiederholen">

  </div>
  <div class="form-bottom"><a class="abort-btn" href="{{route("admin.users.index")}}">Abbrechen</a>
    <button class="action-btn" type="submit">Nutzer anlegen</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

**Goal**

I want to implement dynamicly created checkboxes with the possible roles, so that the admin can assign the roles by creating a user.
I tried it like this:

```
<div class="row-container">
    @foreach ($roles as $role)

<input type="checkbox" name="roles[]" value="{{ $role->id}}">
  {{Form::label("body", $role->role)}}
  @endforeach
  </div>
```

**Questions**

1. So how is it possible to check one of the boxes by default?
2. And how should the code look like in the RegisterController for getting the values from the checkboxes and connect roles with user?

**Edit**

Answer for the second question:

In the RegisterController Replace:

```
$role = Role::select("id")->where("role", "student")->first();

$user->roles()->attach($role);
```

with:

```
$user->roles()->attach($data['roles']);
```

Found it at [this Laravel news article](https://laravel-news.com/authorization-gates).

You can find the whole repo [here](https://gitlab.com/leonp5/bueffelhilfe).

Thanks in advance for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

There is an easyer way.

```
return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        ])->assignRole('RoleYouWant');
```

Just check the role you want to use.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).